# My web-based javascript game is not very sensitive to onkeyup events. How can I make the program detect all keystrokes and not just some of them?

Tags: javascript, detection, keyup

I am making a web-based horse-racing game for two players where one horse is controlled using the arrow keys and the other is controlled using asdw keys. I use html and javascript. My problem is the program only seems to detect the keyup events some of the time (about 65% of the time) so the game is not very responsive to the keystrokes. My code is as follows:

My relevant html code is:

```
<body onkeyup="steer(event)" onload = "init()">
```

My relevant javascript is:

```
function init(){
    ...code that counts 3,2,1,go!...
    setTimeout(function(){doMove();}, 3000);
}

function steer(event){
    key = (event.keyCode);
    if(key == 38) up();
    if(key == 40) dn();
    if(key == 37) lt();
    if(key == 39) rt();
    if(key == 87) up2();
    if(key == 83) dn2();
    if(key == 65) lt2();
    if(key == 68) rt2();
  }
}
function doMove(){

    ...code for moving the horses...
    setTimeout(doMove, 5);


}
```

The up(),dn() etc.. functions just have code for changing the horses' speeds based on the keyup events.

The program only detects 65% of keystrokes (approx.) even when only one player is playing (it has nothing to do with simultaneous keystrokes).

Comment: Just as suggestion:  `key = (event.keyCode || event.which);`. But isn't the answer, just a note :)

Comment: currently `key` is a global variable rather than local to the steer function. First try using `var key` instead of `key`. Probably not the answer, but it'll cut out a few potential bugs.

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't detect keystrokes? Did you log each call to `steer`? Is your keyboard alright? Btw, usually you hook onkeydown instead of -up.

Answer (score 0):

using this jsFiddle[key tracking code](http://jsfiddle.net/YCJLg/) I can't seem to make it miss a key capture, It might be that another element is capturing and preventing bubble up on the event, or perhaps the browser is being overwhelmed with the motion (I change the settimeout to a setinterval which should be easier on the clients).

Also I changed it to use a switch, and key codes that didn't require the use of a shift key

```
   var steer = function (event) {
   var key = (event.keyCode || event.which);

   switch (key) {
       case 73:
           up();
           break;
       case 75:
           dn();
           break;
       case 74:
           lt();
           break;
       case 76:
           rt();
           break;
       case 87:
           up2();
           break;
       case 83:
           dn2();
           break;
       case 65:
           lt2();
           break;
       case 68:
           rt2();
           break;
      }
   };
```

Comment: Still didn't work. I changed key to a local variable and added event.which. I also tried increasing setTimeout to delay 15ms instead of 5, but still didn't work. I know it wasn't making it to the steer() function at all sometimes, because I put in an alert("hi") there and it only said "hi" about 65% of the time I did a keystroke. My keyboard works fine I know because I can type without problems. I'm using keyup instead of keydown because two people are supposed to be playing simultaneously and I want to force them to let go of their key to move their horse.

Comment: Omigod! I just figured out my mistake! I'm sorry, it was in the code I was using. Just a logic error on my part. Sorry for troubling you. Thanks to Jeff Mayeur for his help. It was during my investigation of the code you typed in JSFiddle that I found my error. Thanks again!